# Firefox Ver 29 css hack @-moz-document url-prefix() not working

Tags: css, firefox

I used this firefox css target:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
```

but it doesnt work unless i put an `!important` to it.

Is there any other way around? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This case is likely because you have a more specific selector that is overriding it. Try searching for the property in the 'Computed' tab of the Firefox dev tools.