# Set Css just for Mozilla

Tags: html, css

I want to set some css just for Mozilla. I wrote these css:

```css
 @-moz-document url-prefix() {
    .button{
        background-color: red;
        border: 1px solid red;
        border-radius: 3px;
     }
 }
```

My problem is these aren't work! How can i fix this?
Thank you for help.

Comment: CHECK you are mentioning `.button` class

Comment: Append this code after every other css code and check if you need an !important

Comment: @Sam1604: My class name is '.meh-btn' , i wrote '.button' here for example.

Comment: @ThanasisGrammatopoulos: I add !important but it doesn't change!

Comment: "Doesn't work" meaning, the styles are applied in no browsers, or all browsers, or...? Also, where did you see that an empty url will work? You may need to try `regexp("*")`. In any case, why do you want to limit this rule to Mozilla?

Comment: @torazaburo: I mean that these styles doesn't apply in mozilla. I wrote an example here for say what is my problem but my styles are another things. in url what i need to write? I search and all examples that i see are wrote like this!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123063/what-does-moz-document-url-prefix-do

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668783/firefox-ver-29-css-hack-moz-document-url-prefix-not-working

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally wrong with what you are doing. Try some tests. First, make sure `@-moz-document` is working, by trying a rule such as `@-moz-document url-prefix() { body: { background: yellow; } }` (which works for me). Then, as other commenters have alluded to, examine the element with class `button` in the style inspector, and see what styles are betting applied; perhaps the properties you are specifying are being overridden by a rule of greater specificity.

Comment: Also, lint your entire CSS file. Check to make sure there is not an error in the preceding rule which might be swallowing this one.

Comment: @torazaburo: Every thing is ok but i don't understand why if i move css from html file to css file, it doesn't work!!!

Comment: @ElhamGdz Most likely because (1) your CSS file is not being found/read in (2) there's some error elsewhere in your CSS file that is swallowing this rule (3) the ordering implied by where you put this rule in your CSS file vs. where it falls when included directly in HTML is causing cascade problems which are causing your rule to get overridden.